# What factors need to be considered to decide the radius of a bubble map or is there a generic formula?

Tags: leaflet, mapping, folium

I recently started with GIS and I am learning as I go about implementing things.
Take the case of [JHU Dashboard](https://coronavirus.jhu.edu/map.html) or the first world map in this [NYT article](https://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2020/world/coronavirus-maps.html) or the maps in this [Guardian article](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2020/apr/01/coronavirus-world-map-countries-most-cases-and-deaths), what I do not yet understand is **how do they decide the radius of the bubble on the maps**?

In some maps I can see a discrete nature of radius like -
[image]

But what I do not understand is that we **do not know the upper limit** of the numbers we would end up mapping. Moreover in most of the maps it is **not discrete** but continuous.

Especially for me, I made a [website](https://armsp.github.io/covid19.in/) too where I display India's infections as an `iframe`. I arbitrarily multiply the cases with 2000 to *make them look good on the screen*. But then a few days ago the numbers went up a lot and now everything looks out of proportion even after *reducing the multiplying factor from 2000 to 1500*.

I just feel very bad about not knowing how to correctly represent [this data](https://github.com/armsp/covid19.in/blob/master/datasets/statewise_distribution/2020-04-03.csv).

**Additional Info** -
I use [folium](https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/) to make an html which I embed as [`iframe`](https://github.com/armsp/covid19.in/blob/master/foliummap.html). Folium uses Leaflet internally.

Comment: One of the main policies of this site is **focused question**, which means one question per question. Please edit your question and limit it to only one question.

Comment: @TomazicM sorry about that. Deleted them.

Comment: @TomazicM I have removed  the secondary questions

Comment: It looks like this question is more suitable for data visualization at Stats site: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-visualization. It has no clear GIS part.

Comment: Can you migrate it to that site? I don't have the reputation to do that. If I ask another question there then it will be flagged since I have asked it here too.

Comment: I don't have that king of rights, I hope some of moderators will notice this conversation.

Comment: @TomazicM One of our moderators (whuber) moderates both GIS and stats so I'll try and alert him to this question.  He may be happy to migrate it but the expedient, and I think the SE preferred action on migration requests nowadays, is to have the asker delete their question from here, and to ask it there instead.